# Installing a windows virtual machine in a linux docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, vagrant

I have tried to follow this article:

> https://medium.com/axon-technologies/installing-a-windows-virtual-machine-in-a-linux-docker-container-c78e4c3f9ba1
>
> The Dockerfile can be found in the bottom part of the article

When I do that I get the following error:

First I got a problem regarding setting the TZ so I added the this:

> ENV TZ=Europe/Stockholm RUN ln -snf /user/share/userinfo/$TZ
>
> RUN ln -snf /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

Then I got an error regarding that installation of vagrant was not an debian archive file so I changed it to this:

```
RUN wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/2.3.4/vagrant_2.3.4-1_amd64.deb
-O vagrant_2.3.4-1_amd64.deb 
RUN dpkg -i vagrant_2.3.4-1_amd64.deb
```

Now I have got the following error which I do not understand how to solve:

```
==> default: You are trying to forward to privileged ports (ports <= 1024). Most
==> default: operating systems restrict this to only privileged process (typically
==> default: processes running as an administrative user). This is a warning in case
==> default: the port forwarding doesn't work. If any problems occur, please try a
==> default: port higher than 1024.
==> default: Forwarding ports...
==> default: 3389 (guest) => 3389 (host) (adapter eth0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
      89: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/logging-2.3.1/lib/logging/diagnostic_context.rb:474:in `block in create_with_logging_context'
      88: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in run'
      87: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:203:in `action'
      86: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:203:in `call'
      85: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:631:in `lock'
      84: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:217:in `block in action'
      83: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:248:in `action_raw'
      82: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:101:in `run'
      81: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
      80: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:101:in `block in run'
      79: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:180:in `call'
      78: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:48:in `call'
      77: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
      76: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:48:in `call'
      75: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_check_outdated.rb:93:in `call'
      74: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:48:in `call'
      73: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
      72: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:101:in `run'
      71: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
      70: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:101:in `block in run'
      69: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:180:in `call'
      68: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:48:in `call'
      67: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:127:in `block in finalize_action'
      66: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:48:in `call'
      65: from /root/.vagrant.d/gems/2.7.6/gems/vagrant-libvirt-0.11.2/lib/vagrant-libvirt/action/cleanup_on_failure.rb:21:in `call'
      64: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:48:in `call'
      63: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:80:in `call'
      62: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:48:in `call'
      61: from /root/.vagrant.d/gems/2.7.6/gems/vagrant-libvirt-0.11.2/lib/vagrant-libvirt/action/set_name_of_domain.rb:34:in `call'
      60: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:48:in `call'
      59: from /root/.vagrant.d/gems/2.7.6/gems/vagrant-libvirt-0.11.2/lib/vagrant-libvirt/action/handle_storage_pool.rb:63:in `call'
      58: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:48:in `call'
      57: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box.rb:56:in `call'
      56: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:48:in `call'
      55: from /root/.vagrant.d/gems/2.7.6/gems/vagrant-libvirt-0.11.2/lib/vagrant-libvirt/action/handle_box_image.rb:127:in `call'
      54: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:48:in `call'
      53: from /root/.vagrant.d/gems/2.7.6/gems/vagrant-libvirt-0.11.2/lib/vagrant-libvirt/action/create_domain_volume.rb:97:in `call'
      52: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:48:in `call'
      51: from /root/.vagrant.d/gems/2.7.6/gems/vagrant-libvirt-0.11.2/lib/vagrant-libvirt/action/resolve_disk_settings.rb:143:in `call'
      50: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:48:in `call'
      49: from /root/.vagrant.d/gems/2.7.6/gems/vagrant-libvirt-0.11.2/lib/vagrant-libvirt/action/create_domain.rb:452:in `call'
      48: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:48:in `call'
      47: from /root/.vagrant.d/gems/2.7.6/gems/vagrant-libvirt-0.11.2/lib/vagrant-libvirt/action/create_networks.rb:98:in `call'
      46: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:48:in `call'
      45: from /root/.vagrant.d/gems/2.7.6/gems/vagrant-libvirt-0.11.2/lib/vagrant-libvirt/action/create_network_interfaces.rb:197:in `call'
      44: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:48:in `call'
      43: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
      42: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:101:in `run'
      41: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
      40: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:101:in `block in run'
      39: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:180:in `call'
      38: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:48:in `call'
      37: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:127:in `block in finalize_action'
      36: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:48:in `call'
      35: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
      34: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:101:in `run'
      33: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
      32: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:101:in `block in run'
      31: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:180:in `call'
      30: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:48:in `call'
      29: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:127:in `block in finalize_action'
      28: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:48:in `call'
      27: from /root/.vagrant.d/gems/2.7.6/gems/vagrant-libvirt-0.11.2/lib/vagrant-libvirt/action/prepare_nfs_valid_ids.rb:14:in `call'
      26: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:48:in `call'
      25: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/plugins/synced_folders/nfs/action_cleanup.rb:25:in `call'
      24: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:48:in `call'
      23: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced_folder_cleanup.rb:28:in `call'
      22: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:48:in `call'
      21: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/delayed.rb:19:in `call'
      20: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:48:in `call'
      19: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced_folders.rb:87:in `call'
      18: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:48:in `call'
      17: from /root/.vagrant.d/gems/2.7.6/gems/vagrant-libvirt-0.11.2/lib/vagrant-libvirt/action/prepare_nfs_settings.rb:21:in `call'
      16: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:48:in `call'
      15: from /root/.vagrant.d/gems/2.7.6/gems/vagrant-libvirt-0.11.2/lib/vagrant-libvirt/action/share_folders.rb:22:in `call'
      14: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:48:in `call'
      13: from /root/.vagrant.d/gems/2.7.6/gems/vagrant-libvirt-0.11.2/lib/vagrant-libvirt/action/set_boot_order.rb:22:in `call'
      12: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:48:in `call'
      11: from /root/.vagrant.d/gems/2.7.6/gems/vagrant-libvirt-0.11.2/lib/vagrant-libvirt/action/start_domain.rb:568:in `call'
      10: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:48:in `call'
       9: from /root/.vagrant.d/gems/2.7.6/gems/vagrant-libvirt-0.11.2/lib/vagrant-libvirt/action/wait_till_up.rb:51:in `call'
       8: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:48:in `call'
       7: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/wait_for_communicator.rb:71:in `call'
       6: from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.3.4/gems/vagrant-2.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:48:in `call'
       5: from /root/.vagrant.d/gems/2.7.6/gems/vagrant-libvirt-0.11.2/lib/vagrant-libvirt/action/forward_ports.rb:34:in `call'
       4: from /root/.vagrant.d/gems/2.7.6/gems/vagrant-libvirt-0.11.2/lib/vagrant-libvirt/action/forward_ports.rb:39:in `forward_ports'
       3: from /root/.vagrant.d/gems/2.7.6/gems/vagrant-libvirt-0.11.2/lib/vagrant-libvirt/action/forward_ports.rb:39:in `each'
       2: from /root/.vagrant.d/gems/2.7.6/gems/vagrant-libvirt-0.11.2/lib/vagrant-libvirt/action/forward_ports.rb:51:in `block in forward_ports'
       1: from /root/.vagrant.d/gems/2.7.6/gems/vagrant-libvirt-0.11.2/lib/vagrant-libvirt/action/forward_ports.rb:134:in `redirect_port'
/root/.vagrant.d/gems/2.7.6/gems/vagrant-libvirt-0.11.2/lib/vagrant-libvirt/action/forward_ports.rb:134:in `spawn': No such file or directory - ssh (Errno::ENOENT)
```

After I used google I found someone with the same stacktrace on another page where someone had answered that DetectionLab was installed on another drive and needed to be installed on the same drive as Vagrant. I can´t see anything about DetectionLab in the instructions/Dockerfile. I have googled but not understand how to install DetectionLab in the same container and setup the Dockerfile correct.

Does anyone have any clue or can assist me?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, according to the error message, ssh is missing.
I solved it by adding ssh and sshd in the Dockerfile, before the ENTRYPOINT:

```
 RUN apt-get install -y openssh-server openssh-client
```

Comment: Interesting. I moved away from this but will see if I can try this again and get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that repository that i have created that solve this issue:
[windows in Linux docker container](https://github.com/vaggeliskls/windows-in-docker-container)

1. Create/Update the environmental file .env

```
MEMORY=8000 # 8GB
CPU=4
DISK_SIZE=100
```

2. Create docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  win10:
    image: ghcr.io/vaggeliskls/windows-in-docker-container:latest
    env_file: .env
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    privileged: true
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
      - SYS_ADMIN
    volumes:
      - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup
    devices:
      - /dev/kvm
      - /dev/net/tun
    ports:
      - 3389:3389
```

More info on dev.to article: [windows in Linux docker container](https://dev.to/vaggeliskls/windows-vm-inside-a-linux-docker-container-54ol)